# Is it Okay to remove thanking phrases in questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

Some of the new users write phrases like *thank u*, *thanks in advance* etc.,

Although these phrases show respect or gratitude towards the voluntary contribution by other users, they are not productive enough to present in question.

While improving the other users question, can I remove such phrases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you *can* and *should* remove those sentences, as [our policy](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) states

> **Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks and other chit chat.**
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. Your user page belongs to you, so fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!
>
> **Thanks and other statements of appreciation are unnecessary, and like other chit chat should not be included.**
>
> **If you use signatures, taglines, greetings, thanks or other chit chat, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.**